# Get previous quarter start and end date in Crystal Reports

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Like many have asked (but not for Crystal Reports that I can find), I'm looking for how to get the previous quarter start and end dates.

Since today is 7/10/2014, I can use

```
DateAdd("Q", -1, CurrentDate)
```

and it returns 4/10/2104  12:00:00AM

What I want is the previous quarter start and end dates.  For today, that would be 4/1/2014 and 6/30/2014.  In October, it should instead return 7/1/2014 and 9/30/2014.  I only want the date part, not the time.

I'm looking through the Crystal Date and Time and Date Ranges options, and just not seeing what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first date in the quarter, the following will work:

```
dateVar PrevQuarterDate := Date(DateAdd("Q", -1, CurrentDate));
dateVar PrevQuarterStart := Date(Year(PrevQuarterDate),Month(PrevQuarterDate),1);
PrevQuarterStart;
```

And the last date is similar:

```
dateVar PrevQuarterDate := Date(DateAdd("Q", -1, CurrentDate));
dateVar PrevQuarterEnd := Date(Year(PrevQuarterDate),Month(PrevQuarterDate)+3,1)-1;
PrevQuarterEnd;
```

It turns out the above will **NOT** work if the previous quarter is also in a previous year.  The following is better.  There's enough code to put in your own date and display the results, so it can be checked, too.

```
dateVar ToDaysDate := CurrentDate; //  Date(2014,02,11);
dateVar PrevQDtDate := Date(DateAdd("Q", -1, ToDaysDate));
dateVar PrevQStart := dateserial(year(PrevQDtDate),(datepart("q",DateAdd ("q", -1, ToDaysDate))*3)-2, 1);
DateVar PrevQEnd := dateserial(year(ToDaysDate),datepart('q',ToDaysDate)*3-2,1-1);
StringVar DispDates;
DispDates := totext(PrevQStart) + "-" + totext(PrevQEnd);
DispDates;
```

Answer (score -1):

First date of previous quarter:

```
dateVar     myDate  := currentDate; 
numberVar   myMonth := Month(dateadd("q", -1, myDate));
numberVar   myYear  := Year(dateadd("q", -1, myDate));

myMonth := myMonth - ((myMonth + 2) MOD 3);

date(myYear, myMonth, 1);
```

Last date of pervious quarter:

```
dateVar     myDate := currentDate;
numberVar   myMonth := Month(myDate);
numberVar   myYear  := Year(myDate);

myMonth := myMonth - ((myMonth + 2) MOD 3);

date(dateadd("d", -1, date(myYear, myMonth, 1)));
```