# Get end date of the current Quarter in Crystal Reports

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I need to display the end day of the current quarter. I found this code:

```
dateVar ToDaysDate := CurrentDate; //  Date(2014,02,11);
dateVar PrevQDtDate := Date(DateAdd("Q", -1, ToDaysDate));
dateVar PrevQStart := dateserial(year(PrevQDtDate),(datepart("q",DateAdd ("q", -1, ToDaysDate))*3)-2, 1);
DateVar PrevQEnd := dateserial(year(ToDaysDate),datepart('q',ToDaysDate)*3-2,1-1);
StringVar DispDates;
DispDates := totext(PrevQStart) + "-" + totext(PrevQEnd);
DispDates;
```

..but I can't figure out how to display the last day of the current quarter

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ToText(DateAdd ("q", -1,currentdate))+" - "+ ToText(DateAdd("d", -1,DateAdd ("q", 0,currentdate)))
```

Comment: sorry @Siva, I was typing my answer in the wrong place :)

Answer (score 0):

as your post shows you did a research and I guess you find below post

[Get previous quarter start and end date in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687267/get-previous-quarter-start-and-end-date-in-crystal-reports)

where the @thursdaysgeek answered the question, now for current quarter last day just replace -1 with a 0

```
dateVar PrevQuarterDate := Date(DateAdd("Q", 0, CurrentDate));
dateVar PrevQuarterEnd :=  Date(Year(PrevQuarterDate),Month(PrevQuarterDate)+3,1);
PrevQuarterEnd;
```